# Can't activate shortcut on intellij products

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

## Description

I'm using some intellij products (WebStorm, PHPStorm) and Android Studio and have the same issue with both of theses.

I have an azerty keyboard, with a french layout.

I can type without issue in these softs, but I can't activate shortcuts.

When I try to activate a shortcut (e.g ctrl+z), the activated shortcut is ctrl+w.

the shortcut is correctly triggered, but with the wrong keyboard layout. It seems that when I type, my french keyboard is used, but when I want to use a shortcut, the english layout seems to be used.

Is this a known bug (if so, I've not found any mentions about it), or did I miss something?

## What I've tried

I'm running on Fedora 29, with Gnome 3.

I've tried to see if it wasn't reproductible with others softs (e.g firefox/ vscode), and I can't reproduce this.

I've tried to see if it wasn't based on my keyboard settings, so I ran `xev` to monitor the output of pressed keys. I can't reproduce this issue.

In intellij settings, I've tried to set `Keymap` > `Prefer key position over key char with national layout` both true and false, it doesn't seem to change anything.

## Current situation

Here is an exemple of a shortcut definition in Android Studio.

I pressed `A` to `Y` keys on my french keyboard (which output A,Z,E,R,T,Y), and then press the same keys with ctrl (which output ctrl+Q instead of ctrl+A and so on)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eg0F.jpg

## Expected situation (tl;dr)

I expect that when I press ctrl+a, the shortcut triggered inside intellij products is ctrl+a instead of ctrl+q

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed a known bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165950
In the bug report another workaround is mentioned for Gnome 3:

> Re-order the languages in Settings > Language and Region tab, put English(US) first of the input source list.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by running `setxkbmap fr`. I don't know why this is required by intellij products, but it works.